# security realm authorize one login attempt

Tags: java, security, glassfish, ejb

i'm using glassfish 3.1.1 with ejb 3.0 and a swing client and i have configured a jdbc realm for security purpose.
Everything work fine except one thing, if the user fail to log (wrong login or password) the login dialog is never showed again and the client send automatically the old login/password to the server .
How can i fix this ?
Thanks.

edit this the code of the authentification handler

```
public class ociCallBackHandler implements javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler {

public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) {
    try {


        String login = null;
        char[] mdp = null;

        while (login == null || login.length() < 2) {
            ArrayList out = GuiLogin.getLogin();

            login = (String) out.get(0);

            mdp = (char[]) out.get(1);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("dans boucle");
            if (callbacks[i] instanceof TextOutputCallback) {
                // display the message according to the specified type
                TextOutputCallback toc = (TextOutputCallback) callbacks[i];
                switch (toc.getMessageType()) {
                    case TextOutputCallback.INFORMATION:
                        System.out.println("info");
                        System.out.println(toc.getMessage());

                        break;
                    case TextOutputCallback.ERROR:
                        System.out.println("error");
                        System.out.println("ERROR: " + toc.getMessage());
                        break;
                    case TextOutputCallback.WARNING:
                        System.out.println("warning");
                        System.out.println("WARNING: " + toc.getMessage());
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("inconuue");
                        throw new IOException("Unsupported message type: "
                                + toc.getMessageType());
                }
            } else if (callbacks[i] instanceof TextInputCallback) {
                System.out.println("textINputCallback");
                TextInputCallback tic = (TextInputCallback) callbacks[i];
                System.err.print(tic.getPrompt());
                System.err.flush();
                tic.setText("read");
            } else if (callbacks[i] instanceof NameCallback) {
                // prompt the user for a username
                NameCallback nc = (NameCallback) callbacks[i];


                nc.setName(login);
            } else if (callbacks[i] instanceof PasswordCallback) {
                // prompt the user for sensitive information
                PasswordCallback pc = (PasswordCallback) callbacks[i];


                pc.setPassword(mdp);


            } else {
                throw new UnsupportedCallbackException(callbacks[i], "Unrecognized Callback");
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("exceptionn");
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Well, without seeing the code in person, it would difficult to provide a definite answer. My guess is that your Swing application is caching credentials, but like most guesses it could be wrong. So, please post the code.

Comment: ok , i have posted the code above . Thanks